# Knight's Tour in Java (recursive), using Graph and DFS

Tags: java, graph, depth-first-search, knights-tour, bag

I'm trying to calculate all possible knight moves on a 5x5 field:

To do this, I'm trying to use a DFS (Depth First Search) class and a Graph class.

I thought it might be too much code (and maybe not relevant enough) to paste these entire classes in this post, so I display them here:

[Graph.java](http://codetidy.com/7734/)

[DepthFirstSearch.java](http://codetidy.com/7735/)

Graph.java uses Bag.java:

[Bag.java](http://codetidy.com/7736/)

The field would look something like this (using an id for each field):

```
0  1  2  3  4
5  6  7  8  9
10 11 12 13 14
15 16 17 18 19
20 21 22 23 24
```

The following attributes are used in the CalculatePath method, which should calculate the amount of possible tours a knight could take from a specific square to visit each square exactly once (should take a minute or two to solve it).

The possible Knight's steps are defined (in the main class) like this (using edges of a Graph, G):

```
G.addEdge(0, 11);
G.addEdge(0, 7);

G.addEdge(1, 8);
G.addEdge(1, 10);
G.addEdge(1, 12);

G.addEdge(2, 5);
G.addEdge(2, 9);
G.addEdge(2, 11);
G.addEdge(2, 13);

G.addEdge(3, 6);
G.addEdge(3, 12);
G.addEdge(3, 14);

G.addEdge(4, 7);
G.addEdge(4, 13);

G.addEdge(5, 2);
G.addEdge(5, 12);
G.addEdge(5, 16);

G.addEdge(6, 15);
G.addEdge(6, 17);
G.addEdge(6, 3);
G.addEdge(6, 13);

G.addEdge(7, 0);
G.addEdge(7, 4);
G.addEdge(7, 10);
G.addEdge(7, 14);
G.addEdge(7, 16);
G.addEdge(7, 18);

G.addEdge(8, 1);
G.addEdge(8, 17);
G.addEdge(8, 19);
G.addEdge(8, 11);

G.addEdge(9, 2);
G.addEdge(9, 12);
G.addEdge(9, 18);

G.addEdge(10, 1);
G.addEdge(10, 21);
G.addEdge(10, 7);
G.addEdge(10, 17);

G.addEdge(11, 0);
G.addEdge(11, 2);
G.addEdge(11, 20);
G.addEdge(11, 22);
G.addEdge(11, 8);
G.addEdge(11, 18);

G.addEdge(12, 1);
G.addEdge(12, 3);
G.addEdge(12, 21);
G.addEdge(12, 23);
G.addEdge(12, 5);
G.addEdge(12, 9);
G.addEdge(12, 15);
G.addEdge(12, 19);

G.addEdge(13, 2);
G.addEdge(13, 4);
G.addEdge(13, 22);
G.addEdge(13, 24);
G.addEdge(13, 6);
G.addEdge(13, 16);

G.addEdge(14, 3);
G.addEdge(14, 23);
G.addEdge(14, 7);
G.addEdge(14, 17);

G.addEdge(15, 6);
G.addEdge(15, 12);
G.addEdge(15, 22);

G.addEdge(16, 5);
G.addEdge(16, 7);
G.addEdge(16, 13);
G.addEdge(16, 23);

G.addEdge(17, 6);
G.addEdge(17, 8);
G.addEdge(17, 10);
G.addEdge(17, 14);
G.addEdge(17, 20);
G.addEdge(17, 24);

G.addEdge(18, 7);
G.addEdge(18, 9);
G.addEdge(18, 11);
G.addEdge(18, 21);

G.addEdge(19, 8);
G.addEdge(19, 12);
G.addEdge(19, 22);

G.addEdge(20, 11);
G.addEdge(20, 17);

G.addEdge(21, 10);
G.addEdge(21, 12);
G.addEdge(21, 18);

G.addEdge(22, 11);
G.addEdge(22, 13);
G.addEdge(22, 15);
G.addEdge(22, 19);

G.addEdge(23, 12);
G.addEdge(23, 14);
G.addEdge(23, 16);

G.addEdge(24, 13);
G.addEdge(24, 17);

int currentSquare = 20;
calculatePath(currentSquare);
System.out.println("From square " + currentSquare + " there are " + tours + " possible tours.");
```

Here's what I tried to find the possible tours:

```
  private static void calculatePath(int currentSquare) {
        boolean foundChoice = false;
        for (int point : G.adj(currentSquare)) {

            if (dfs.marked(currentSquare)) {
                foundChoice = true;
//              dfs.unmark(currentSquare);
                calculatePath(point);
            }
        }
        if (!foundChoice) {
            tours++;
            dfs.unmark(currentSquare);
        }
        System.out.println(currentSquare + " - tours: " + tours);
    }
```

For example, if I try to call this recursive function by `calculatePath(20)`, it should return all possible tours (`tours`) from that square, using every square on the field.

Unmarked squares are squares that have already been reached and shouldn't be visitable anymore in the same tour.

Now, the problem is that I'm not able to let `CalculatePath` skip the already visited squares (the output shows it goes from 20 to 17 and from 20 to 11, and then stops the recursive method).

Also, the method doesn't calculate multiple tours, yet. I want to calculate one path correctly first and eventually calculate all possible tours.

All code I'm using is privided in this post - included the classes in the links above.

Answer (score 1):

There are *still :)* a number of issues with this code but it looks like you are making progress.

Your method `DepthFirstSearch.marked` seems wrong to me. I would have thought it should return `true` if it successfully changed the mark from `false` to `true`. Here you are only returning the value of `marked[w]`.

Your `DepthFirstSearch` constructor seems to be attempting to mark all of the adjacent (and all of their adjacent points). This seems strange - how do you expect this to work? The normal DFS mechanism for avoiding loops is to leave a mark at each location you have touched as you recurse and remoive the mark as the recursion completes. Here you seem to be marking all squares at the start and then unmarking them when you've completed one round of all adjacents without finding a marked one.

Comment: Thanks for answering again(: . The `DepthFirstSearch.marked` method just checks whether a square is marked or not. The constructor should mark all squares in the beginning, so the `CalculatePath` method is able to unmark the squares that are already visited.

Comment: @MJM - This is why I explained the `normal` technique of mark - recurse - unmark. You can't just mark everything at the start and only unmark in your algorithm. Say you start at `0` and first search `7` and then `11` but while checking `11` you land on `10` and consider visiting `7`, now it is unmarked and you are blocked from doing so.

Comment: How would you recommend doing it instead? I mean, how should I put this into code? I didn't expect the DFS class to be incorrect, since I'm just supposed to use it, not edit it. It's a defined class written by Sedgewick and Wayne, authors of the book Algorithms - wherein I found and used this class.

Comment: @MJM - From the book - *The <tt>DepthFirstSearch</tt> class represents a data type for **determining the vertices connected to a given source vertex** <em>s</em>
in an undirected graph.* So it can only give you a reachable/non-reachable and won't be any use for traversals. The [DepthFirstPaths](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41graph/DepthFirstPaths.java.html) may be of more use perhaps.